# Symmetry Lines in two graphs

Tags: algebra-precalculus, symmetry

i was asked to answer this question and i was curious about something while solving it
the question goes like this
$f(x)=-\frac{1}{2}x^2 +2x +6$
and
$g(x)=-1.2x^2+4.8x+6$
show that the graphs have the same symmetry line.

anyway my question is:
is it possible to determine that two graphs have the same symmetry line  without finding the symmetry lines by caculating 2 points on the graph for both of them.

by the way thanks for helping me

Comment: The axis of symmetry of $y=ax^2+bx+c$ is $x=\frac{-b}{2a}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Rearrange:
$$f(x)=-\frac12(x-2)^2+8\\
g(x)=-1.2(x-2)^2+10.8$$